# Adding Windows Media Player to c# program

Tags: c#, audio, media-player

I'm looking to start using windows media player in my c# application. My first problem was locating wmp.dll in my Windows 7 install, which was not in \windows\system32\ but rather in C:\Windows\winsxs\amd64_microsoft-windows-mediaplayer-core_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.17514_none_698fc88e65b943d6

So I have added this as an assembly in SharpDevelop, and expected to be able to use this, via 'using WMPLib;' at the start of my code. This namespace name cannot be found.

Does anyone know what is going on here aside from my lack of insight?

Update:

I added references to PresentationCore and WindowsBase, and tried to use System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer:

```
            WMP_EATEN_PILL = new System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer();
            WMP_EATEN_PILL.Open(new System.Uri(@"D:\Programming\SFX\EATEN_PILL\Hit_43_s.wav"));
            WMP_EATEN_PILL.Play();
```

This doesn't play a sound. The path is correct (and I think I don't need to escape the back-slashes right?) so I'm not sure what is happening here.

Is there anything obviously wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding it in references, Right click your project click add reference and add select Windows Media Player, then click the OK button.

Comment: I discovered firstly that media player was not enabled in Windows. Following that I had to install Windows 7 SDK. This itself was a pain, but once that was complete I've now got Windows Media Player running. I implement a bank of 5 players for every sound effect to achieve simultaneous sounds.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use double backslash on your path.

Try this:

```
var WMP_EATEN_PILL = new System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer();
WMP_EATEN_PILL.Open(new System.Uri(@"D:\\Programming\\SFX\\EATEN_PILL\\Hit_43_s.wav"));
WMP_EATEN_PILL.Play();
```